# Hive automatically filtering NULL in NOT IN condition

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have a Hive table in AWS named `table1` with only one column, which looks like shown below:

```
COL1
(null)
active
```

Trying below query

```sql
select * 
from table1 
where COL1 NOT IN ('reversed')
```

Hive is returning only one row

```
COL1
active
```

Why is it not returning the record with (null)?

I understand that the fix is to modify the condition as below. But I want to debug this issue so that this doesn't happen on other queries

```
where coalesce(COL1,"") NOT IN ('reversed')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how all RDBMS systems treat `null` value.

`null` has a special meaning - something like `not defined`

When you check:

```
COL1 NOT IN ('reversed')
```

the following comparisons will be made:

```
(null) != reversed
active != reversed
...
```

and only those that return `true` will be returned:

```
scala> spark.sql("SELECT 'active' != 'reversed'").show
+-------------------------+
|(NOT (active = reversed))|
+-------------------------+
|                     true|
+-------------------------+


scala> spark.sql("SELECT null != 'reversed'").show
+---------------------------------------+
|(NOT (CAST(NULL AS STRING) = reversed))|
+---------------------------------------+
|                                   null|
+---------------------------------------+
```

as you can see: `(null) != 'reversed'` doesn't return `true` - that's why you don't see it in the result set

Moreover:

```
scala> spark.sql("SELECT (null) = 'reversed'").show
+---------------------------------+
|(CAST(NULL AS STRING) = reversed)|
+---------------------------------+
|                             null|
+---------------------------------+
```

Because of that we have `IS NULL`, `IS NOT NULL`, `COALESCE`, etc. methods and functions, that allow us to work with `NULL` values

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! It helped.